# Howto create a jquery-like $() wrapper function?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a small code plugin which allows you to do some things with arrays. I do not wish to add the functions to the array object using a prototype construction, what I want is that people can do something like:

```
arrayFunction( [1, 2, 3] ).someSpecialArrayFunction();
```

Thus leaving the normal array object unaltered.
So I came up with the following construction (which was inspired on the jQuery source code) :

```
var arrayFunction = window.arrayFunction = function(array) {
    return new arrayFunction.fn.init(array);
}
arrayFunction.fn = arrayFunction.prototype = {
    init: function(array){
        this.a = array;
        //should I return something here?
    },
    someSpecialArrayFunction: function(){
        //Super cool custom stuff here.
    }
}
```

However this does not work (obviously). What should happen in the init function()?

The error right now is that when I try:

```
 arrayFunction(array).someSpecialArrayFunction();
```

it says that someSpecialArrayFunction() is not a function?

How should one do this?

**edit**
Yes, this is indeed a simpliefied example. The actual thing has way more methods.

Also, I just though of how awesome it would be if it also supported chaning, how would you do that?

Comment: The $ for jquery is actually an object.

Comment: In Javascript, all functions are objects - you actually declare objects using the function keyword, so the jQuery $ is both an object and a function that returns instances of that object. This can take some getting used to...

Comment: Are you looking here for a way to make your example *work* - or for a general pattern for appending methods to a wrapper object by adding them to the wrapper's prototype, e.g. so you can manage large collections of extension methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or simply:

```
var arrayFunction = function(array) {
    var someSpecialArrayFunction = function() {
        // do something with array
    };
    return {
        someSpecialArrayFunction: someSpecialArrayFunction
    }
};
arrayFunction( [1, 2, 3] ).someSpecialArrayFunction();
```

Although be careful with this, if you end up with too many methods It's probably better to use the prototype.

Comment: You should roll back your edit: it doesn't work! The array-variable in your closure will always be bound to the array passed as argument to the first call of myArrayFunction()...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this is the best syntax to get what you want, but I suppose this is a trimmed down example ... Anyways here is a quick way to make it work

```
var arrayFunction = window.arrayFunction = function(array) {
    return new arrayFunction.fn.init(array);
}
arrayFunction.fn = arrayFunction.prototype = {
    init: function(array){
        var a = array;
        return  {
            someSpecialArrayFunction: function(){
                alert (a.join(' - ') ); //Super cool custom stuff here.
            }
        };
    },
}
arrayFunction( [1, 2, 3] ).someSpecialArrayFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

**sktrdie**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425189/howto-create-a-jquery-like-wrapper-function#425276) looks nice.

An additional thing to consider would be to use the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) instead of returning a new object instance with each call to your wrapper. The ExtJS function [Ext.fly](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext) does this; it returns a globally shared instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var mathWrapper = function(array) {
    return {
        mean : function(){
            if (array.length == 0) return(0);
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) total += array[i];
            return(total / array.length);
        },
    };
}
```

Invoking it via something like

```
document.write(mathWrapper([1,2,3,4,5,6]).mean());
```

should return the mean of the array elements.

Comment: This is not memory efficient - use a wrapper object and add the methods to its prototype instead...

Comment: @Christoph - ah... suddenly a whole bunch of things that were confusing me are making sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want t change `Array.prototype`, the only really feasible solution is adding the methods to the specific array object:

```
function doSomething() {}
function doOther() {}

function wrap(array) {
    array.doSomething = doSomething;
    array.doOther = doOther;
    return array;
}
```

Note that I'm not defining `doSomething()` and `doOther()` within `wrap()` - otherwise, we would create new function objects on each call, which is highly inefficient.

A more sophisticated variant would be the following:

```
function doSomething() {}
function doOther() {}

function wrap(array) {
    if(this instanceof arguments.callee) {
        this.doSomething = doSomething;
        this.doOther = doOther;
    }
    else {
        arguments.callee.prototype = array;
        return new arguments.callee;
    }
}
```

Here, we create a new wrapper object (and don't add properties to the array itself). The wrapper object will still have access to all the array's properties. There's a slight catch, though:

```
var foo = wrap([1,2,3]);
document.writeln(foo.length); // writes 3
foo.push(4);
document.writeln(foo.length); // writes 4 in FF, 3 in IE
foo[4] = 5;
foo[5] = 6;
document.writeln(foo.length); // still writes 4?!
```

Using `foo[4] =` will access our wrapper object and the properties `4` and `5` will be set there and not in the array - therefore, its length property won't be updated. In IE, calling `push()` will already fail to correctly update the array...

If your wrapper object doesn't need to 'reroute' calls to the array object, there are other solutions using closures - sktrdie's first example is one of these. I'd argue against them because they will create new function objects with every call as well. What I would do:

```
function wrap(array) {
    if(this instanceof arguments.callee)
        this.array = array;
    else return new arguments.callee(array);
}

wrap.prototype.doSomething = function() {};
wrap.prototype.doOther = function() {};
```

Here, you can access the array in `doSomething()` and `doOther()` via `this.array`.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend the Array object and add your fancy methods to your object.  Then you can make a bridge function that takes an array as an argument and returns your version of array.  That method is by far easier and more useful.